# How to push a class instance into a private array of another class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, inheritance

I have a class as shown below:

```
class RoomUsageList {

constructor()
{
    // private atributes
    this._roomList = [];

}

set roomList(newIns)
{
    this._roomList.push(newIns);
}
}
```

And a function file (in another javascript file), that passes an instace of another class (RoomUsage) to the setter of the RoomUsageList class (above) to as shown below:

```
function saveTap()
{
// create a new class instance when the SAVE button
// is pushed.
let newAddress = document.getElementById('address').value;
let newRoomNo = document.getElementById('roomNumber').value;
let newLightSwitch = document.getElementById('lights').checked;
let newHeatCoolSwitch = document.getElementById('heatingCooling').checked;
let newSeatsUsed = document.getElementById('seatsUsed').value;
let newSeatsTotal = document.getElementById('seatsTotal').value;


let roomUsageIns = new RoomUsage();
roomUsageIns.address = newAddress;
roomUsageIns.roomNumber = newRoomNo;
roomUsageIns.lightsOn = newLightSwitch;
roomUsageIns.heatingCoolingOn = newHeatCoolSwitch;
roomUsageIns.seatsTotal = newSeatsTotal;
roomUsageIns.seatsUsed = newSeatsUsed;

// add the above-created class instance into the RoomUsageList class

let roomUsageList = new RoomUsageList(roomUsageIns);
roomUsageList.roomList = roomUsageIns;

console.log(roomUsageList);

}
```

The output only contains one instance and doesn't push new RoomUsage instances. Why is that so?
I am new to programming, any help would be amazing!

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: It is pushing the new instance. You're just not using arguments in the constructor

Comment: The code is working as expected. I guess your problem is that you redefine `roomUsageList` each time `saveTap` is called.

Comment: Really your `RoomUsage` class should have a `.roomList` property. There should be no `RoomUsageList` class at all. Keep it simple.

Comment: Don't use a setter if you want to `push` (append) to the list. Or if you don't want to append to the list in the setter but overwrite the list, drop the setter altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are creating a new RoomUsageList instance every time the `saveTap` function is called. This is resetting `_roomList` to `[]`.

If you invoke `roomUsageList = new RoomUsageList()` outside of the function, then the setter should work as expected and append new `RoomUsage` instances to the private `_roomList` attribute.

EDIT: Typo
EDIT2: Removed extra console logs in code snippet

```js
class RoomUsage {
  constructor () {
    //
  }  
}

class RoomUsageList {
  constructor () {
    // private attributes
    this._roomList = [];
  }

  set roomList(newIns) {
    const roomList = [...this._roomList, newIns];
    this._roomList = roomList
  }
}

// Create global state
const roomUsageList = new RoomUsageList();

function onFormSubmit (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // create a new class instance when the SAVE button
  // is pushed.
  let newAddress = document.querySelector('.address').value;
  let newRoomNo = document.querySelector('.roomNumber').value;
  let newLightSwitch = document.querySelector('.lights').checked;
  let newHeatCoolSwitch = document.querySelector('.heatingCooling').checked;
  let newSeatsUsed = document.querySelector('.seatsUsed').value;
  let newSeatsTotal = document.querySelector('.seatsTotal').value;

  let roomUsageIns = new RoomUsage();
  roomUsageIns.address = newAddress;
  roomUsageIns.roomNumber = newRoomNo;
  roomUsageIns.lightsOn = newLightSwitch;
  roomUsageIns.heatingCoolingOn = newHeatCoolSwitch;
  roomUsageIns.seatsTotal = newSeatsTotal;
  roomUsageIns.seatsUsed = newSeatsUsed;

  // add the above-created class instance into the RoomUsageList class
  
  roomUsageList.roomList = roomUsageIns;

  console.log(roomUsageList);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="onFormSubmit(event)">
  
  <div>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="address">    
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Room Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="roomNumber">    
  </div>

  <div>    
    <label>Lights</label>
    <input type="text" class="lights">
  </div>

  <div>    
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="heatingCooling">
      Heating/Cooling
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>    
    <label>Seats Used</label>
    <input type="text" class="seatsUsed">
  </div>

  <div>    
    <label>Seats Total</label>
    <input type="text" class="seatsTotal">
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to notice. But after trying your code, the pushing of the new arrays occur by creating a new array, in an array, in an array and so on. I have just modified your code a bit and it works perfectly now, Thanks for the help again!(I've added what i just did as an answer to this question).

Comment: Hm, when I run my code snippet that is not the case. My code uses the spread operator to ensure a flat list: `const roomList = [...this._roomList, newIns];`  Did you do this also? In any case, I think Darek Gala's answer is the better API design. Setters should be used to set a value, rather than partially modifying it. So it would be better to use public methods for adding/removing elements from the private list.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setter` only for setting whole list, not to appending items - for that you can create separate methods, for example `addItem` for appending single item or `addItems` which inserts more than one intem into array

```
class RoomUsageList {

  constructor() {
    this._roomList = [];
  }

  set roomList(roomList) {
    this._roomList = roomList;
  }

  addItem(item) {
    this._roomList.push(item);
  }

  addItems(items) {
    this._roomList.concat(items);
  }
}
```

That's good that you found the solution - with each call of the fuction, new instance was created :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, by adjusting your code slightly the program works perfectly. This is what I have done:

```
//Room Usage List Class
//---------------------
//
class RoomUsageList {

constructor()
{
    // private atributes
    this._roomList = [];

}

set roomList(newIns)
{
    // pushes new array into parent class instance
    this._roomList.push(newIns);
}  
}

//making the parent class instance global
const roomUsageList = new RoomUsageList();

function saveTap()
{
// create a new class instance when the SAVE button
// is pushed.
let newAddress = document.getElementById('address').value;
let newRoomNo = document.getElementById('roomNumber').value;
let newLightSwitch = document.getElementById('lights').checked;
let newHeatCoolSwitch = document.getElementById('heatingCooling').checked;
let newSeatsUsed = document.getElementById('seatsUsed').value;
let newSeatsTotal = document.getElementById('seatsTotal').value;

let roomUsageIns = new RoomUsage();
roomUsageIns.address = newAddress;
roomUsageIns.roomNumber = newRoomNo;
roomUsageIns.lightsOn = newLightSwitch;
roomUsageIns.heatingCoolingOn = newHeatCoolSwitch;
roomUsageIns.seatsTotal = newSeatsTotal;
roomUsageIns.seatsUsed = newSeatsUsed;

// add the above created class instance into the RoomUsageList class
roomUsageList.roomList = roomUsageIns;
console.log(roomUsageList);

}
```